# Transform an HTML sortable list into an array of ActiveRecord object of different class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I’m trying to find the most efficient way to transform a sortable list inside an array of active record object keeping the sortable list order.

I have a class named `Page`, and this class is a page of my cms where I will have a lot of contents from different classes. My class basically is

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Relations
  has_many :contents
  has_many :videos
  has_many :galleries
  has_many :surveys
  has_many :documents

end
```

To manage the page structure I’ using a jQuery sortable plugin: I have in the cms the list of contents, videos etc associated to my page instance and clicking on a “resource” this resource is added to a sortable list.

Basically I create a structure like this:

```
<li class="list-group-item" data-type="Survey" data-id=“1”>Test Survey</li>
<li class="list-group-item" data-type="Video" data-id=“1”>Test Video</li>
<li class="list-group-item" data-type="Video" data-id=“12”>Test Video 2</li>
<li class="list-group-item" data-type="Gallery" data-id=“1”>Test Gallery</li>
```

`data-type` is the element Class, `data-id` is the element ID.

Now I need to create an array with the object of the HTML list, so I'm  looping inside my list and I can query for the relative record one by one.

```
@resources << Class.find(data-id)
```

Using the array `@resources` in my view I can create the ordered list of contents…

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Where/how are you storing the order?  You might consider a polymorphic model in the middle so a `Page has_many :page_contents` and `PageContent` has a polymorphic `belongs_to` to videos, contents. galleries e.t.c. then you can have a position column on `PageContent` to store the ordering

Comment: The order is the list... 
I know that I can create a polymorphic model in the middle... but adding e relation is complex because I have to manage a lot of conditions... 
Here I create a class method Video.find_for_page(id) that return me the video. If the video is deleted, not published, not ready it return nil and the element is not inserted in the array.

Comment: But how are you actually storing the order in the database?  If they all have published e.t.c you can add that to the polymorphic model to solve that issue

Comment: Now every model is stored with a published date and every model has a default order that I must override....